# dynamically modify webkit animation with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, webkit

I would like to use webkit animation with @-webkit-keyframes but being able to dynamically modify the values on the rule, so that the animation is not static.
All the samples I found use a static @-webkit-frames, is there a way to customize with Javascript?

Answer (score 21):

I had to create a new style rule in the loaded style sheets. Seems to work great in chrome 5.0.342.9 beta (at least)

```
var lastSheet = document.styleSheets[document.styleSheets.length - 1];
lastSheet.insertRule("@-webkit-keyframes " + newName + " { from { top: 0px; } to {top: " + newHeight + "px;} }", lastSheet.cssRules.length);
```

and then assign the animation name using element.style

```
element.style.webkitAnimationName = newName;
```

Comment: I know this is a bit late, but still: how would I use this without assigning the animation at the end? I don't want the animation to run then; I am using addClass/removeClass to start the animations with jQuery

Comment: once you have an animation name you can have an existing class that sets the animation. in your style sheet: `.animate {-webkit-animation-name: newName;}`

Answer (score 8):

I wish I could credit for this, but here's a link to someone who managed to modify an existing animation, as opposed to creating a new animation.

http://gitorious.org/webkit/webkit/blobs/438fd0b118bd9c2c82b6ab23956447be9c24f136/LayoutTests/animations/change-keyframes.html

I've ran this to verify that it does, indeed, work.

#### EDIT

So that link is dead and I don't trust Gitorious to maintain URLS anymore so here's a link to a JSFiddle I created to answer a similar question: http://jsfiddle.net/russelluresti/RHhBz/3/

This contains script to find an existing animation, update its values, and assign it to an element to make the animation occur. I have tested this in Chrome 18 and Safari 5.1

Comment: Hi Russell, when you verified this, which browsers did you test in? Thanks!

Comment: Because of cascading creating a new animation will effectively overwrite existing ones with the same name.