# Is it possible to change css animation width javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to make a css function dynamic?

```
.test2
{
    width:200px;
    height: 90%;
    -webkit-animation:myfirst2 linear; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst2 /* Safari and Chrome */
{
    from { height: 0%; } <--this must be dynamic
    to { height: 90%; } <--this must be dynamic
}
```

I want the `from { height: 0%; }` and the `to { height: 90%; }` dynamic with JavaScript.

Is this possible?

Comment: This looks to be what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495829/dynamically-modify-webkit-animation-with-javascript

Comment: Yes, Thanks Callum Macrae. This was the solution i was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the jQuery css() function

```
$('.foo').css({'-webkit-animation': 'myfirst2 linear', '-webkit-animation-duration':  '10s'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery and jQuery animate function 
Here you have a jsfiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/QrbNW/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can easly give in .css

like this

```
 //Fade in Background
             jQuery('#fade').css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}).fadeOut(); //Fade in the fade layer      


       //Apply Margin to Popup
            jQuery('#' + popID).css({
                'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
                'margin-left' : -popMargLeft,
                'display' : 'block'
            });
```